# Java loop extracting month and year between two dates

Tags: java, datetime

I have a `ContratMercan` with 2 `Timestamps` containing `start` and `end` dates. 
I have to create a new entity `SeguimientoSeccion` for each `month` between this 2 dates.

I have 2 questions:

- There is a way to improve it?
- After this I will need to manipulate the `List<SeguimientoSeccion> secciones` to see which one matches other entity... I though about making a `Map` but there can be 2 or more sections in each `month` and `year`

```
private List<SeguimientoSeccion> createSectionsPerMonth(ContratMercan contrato) 
{
    List<SeguimientoSeccion> secciones = new ArrayList<SeguimientoSeccion>();

    Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
    start.setTime(contrato.getPeriodoEntregaIni());
    start.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

    Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance();
    end.setTime(contrato.getPeriodoEntregaFin());
    end.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 2);  // for loop comparison

    for (int month = start.get(Calendar.MONTH), year = start.get(Calendar.YEAR); start.before(end); month = start.get(Calendar.MONTH), year = start.get(Calendar.YEAR)) {
        SeguimientoSeccion seccion = new SeguimientoSeccion();
        seccion.setMonth(month + 1);  // natural month number
        seccion.setYear(year);

        start.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);

        secciones.add(seccion);
    }

    return secciones;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code would be simpler if you used a `Calendar` object as the loop variable.

```
Calendar current = …;
Calendar end = …;

for (; current.before(end); current.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1)) {
    SeguimientoSeccion seccion = new SeguimientoSeccion();
    seccion.setMonth(1 + current.get(Calendar.MONTH));  // natural month number
    seccion.setYear(current.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    secciones.add(seccion);
}
```

Consider implementing a `SeguimientoSeccion.setMonthYear(m, y)` method instead, as it's probably useless to set one of the fields without also setting the other.

Comment: Already implemented, works and looks great.:). Any idea about how to make a `Collection` or `Map` to refer the objects later?